# add event object to my code from bic_calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am tying to use bic_calendar from this link [bic_calendar](http://bichotll.github.io/bic_calendar/)

i use this cod to add the calendar to my website

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

          var monthNames = ["January", "February", "May", "June", "March", "April", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

      
var dayNames = [ "الاحد", "الاثنين", "ثلاثاء", "الاربعاء", "الخميس", "جمعه","سبت"];
      
          $('#calendar').bic_calendar({
              //enable select
              enableSelect: true,
              //set day names
              dayNames: dayNames,
              //set month names
              monthNames: monthNames,
              //show dayNames
              showDays: true,
              //show month controller
              displayMonthController: true,
              //show year controller
              displayYearController: true,
              //change calendar to english format
              startWeekDay: 1,
              //set ajax call
              
              
              reqAjax: {
                  type: 'get',
                  url: 'http://bic.cat/bic_calendar/index.php'
              }
          });

        $('.bic_calendar').removeClass('row');
        $('.table').addClass('table-bordered');
        $('.table.header').removeClass('table-bordered');
      });

        
    </script>
```

and this code run on my site successfuly on my website

i need to add the **Event object** to my code

this is and example on the doc
date(string):
ex: "17/8/1989"
title (string)
ex: "Event Barberà"
link (string)
ex: "http://google.es"
color(string)
ex: "#333"
class (string)
ex: "activo congreso"
content (string)
ex: "Text for the content of popover...description of event...image..."

- if content is not defined it will be a tooltip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to add events to bic_calendar:

By using "events" option (array of event object):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   
    var events = [{
    date: "24/12/2016",
    title: 'an event',
  }, {
    date: "25/12/2016",
    title: 'event 2'
  }];
    
  $('#calendar').bic_calendar({
    events: events
  });
     
});
```

Or/And by using "reqAjax" (json array of event array) option. This option makes a call to a specified url and expects json array of events as a respose:

```
[{
    "date": "24/12/2016",
    "title": "an event"
}, {
    "date": "25/12/2016",
    "title": "event 2"
}]
```

Here is the example of using reqAjax option:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       
      $('#calendar').bic_calendar({
        reqAjax: {
            type: 'get',
            url: 'your url returning json array of events'
        }
      });
         
    });
```